# How to delete WOW64 related entries with Autoruns?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, autorun

I have the following entries in [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns?ranMID=43674&ranEAID=FE4O7wtxe6g&ranSiteID=FE4O7wtxe6g-XjCZXbVrO9x3g2oSJ2O11A&epi=FE4O7wtxe6g-XjCZXbVrO9x3g2oSJ2O11A&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=(ir__r1yq92nqokkf6xgxagoxvfeivv2xqe1ffx3apbvk00)(7795)(1243925)(FE4O7wtxe6g-XjCZXbVrO9x3g2oSJ2O11A)()&irclickid=_r1yq92nqokkf6xgxagoxvfeivv2xqe1ffx3apbvk00), but can't delete them because of access denied error

[image]

What are them and how to force?

---

Am running `Autoruns` as administrator.

Comment: Why do you want to delete these entries?

Comment: My computer works very slow and I am trying to clean all old stuff.

Comment: @Dims , is this satire?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen what are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You should run Autoruns as Administrator.

Alternatively, you could use the menu *File > Run As Administrator*.

Comment: I am running as administrator of course

Comment: In this case, the folder is highly restricted, even for administrators. In any case, the stuff you're trying to delete will not improve performance.

Comment: Broken links are restricted even for administrators? By whom?

Comment: That depends on in which folder they exist. I'm not even sure that these are real entries, or if the error message means that the displayed entry does not fully exist. You might be better off with a registry cleaner, but this should be used with extreme caution (take at least a System Restore backup before using it).